# Replicating C program in assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to replicate a simple C code in a human written assembly code. I've tried my best to research this over the past week, but for every thing I've learned I don't seem to get any closer to accomplishing this goal. I've written the code out in multiple ways that I think should work. in some of the versions of the code my variables don't initialize correctly so the cmp jmp never trigger giving me infinite output lines. in other versions it crashes without output, even when the code I changed would happen after the output line.

```
%include "io.inc"
extern printf ; brings in the printf to be called for output
section .data
section .text
    jar DD 4 ; The jar variable is the primary output of the function during printf
    iar DD 0 ; The iar variable is a counter for a while loop which runs through 8 times
    message: db "num: %d" , 10, 0; will be pushed to stack to make the printf statement work
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    inc dword[iar] ; incraments the iar variable by one.
    mov eax, [iar]; put the iar into eax register so it can be added to the jar variable
    add [jar], eax ;jar= jar + iar
    cmp dword[jar], 20; compare jar to 20 (jar>20)
    jl RE ; if jar is less than 20 skip the next step
    sub  dword[jar], 20; otherwise subtract 20 from j 
RE:  
    mov eax, [jar] ; move the jar variable to the eax register to be pushed to the stack
    push  eax ; push jar for printf
    push message ; push formating for printf
    call printf   ; print the primary output "num: [jar]"
    pop eax ; clear the stack 
    pop eax ; clear the stack   
    cmp dword[iar],8 ; Compare iar to 8 to see if iar has been incremented 8 times   
    jne CMAIN ; if i != 8 jump to cmain
pleaseKillMeNow:
    mov ah,0x4C  ;graceful exit
    int 0x21
```

This code is meant to replicate the following C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    int iar;
    int jar;
    jar=4;
    iar=0;
    while(i<8){
        jar=jar+1;
        if(jar>20){
        jar=jar-20;
        }
        printf("%d",j);
        i++;
        j=j+1;
        i++;
        printf("%d",j);
    }
return j;
}
```

I'd appreciate any direction where I can go to debug this. I'm using SASM to work on this right now. Thank you

Comment: Where is `i` declared/initialized?  Or `j`?  Is this running under DOS (`int 0x21` is a DOS thing)?  Or Windows (`eax` makes me think 32bit)?

Comment: add this and than try a debug again: int i = 0;, int j= 0;

Comment: your variables should be in .data, not in .text

Comment: `jar= jar + iar` in your asm is nothing that's found in the C code

Answer (score 0):

By commenting out the pleasekillmenow: section, and returning declarations to the .data section I got the code to work as expected

```
%include "io.inc"
extern printf ; brings in the printf to be called for output
section .data
    jar DD 4 ; The jar variable is the primary output of the function during printf
    iar DD 0 ; The iar variable is a counter for a while loop which runs through 8 times
    incs DD 1
section .text

    message: db "num: %d" , 10, 0; will be pushed to stack to make the printf statement work
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    mov eax, [iar]; put the iar into eax register so it can be added to the jar variable
    add [jar], eax ;jar= jar + iar
    cmp dword[jar], 20; compare jar to 20 (jar>20)
    jl RE ; if jar is less than 20 skip the next step
    sub  dword[jar], 20; otherwise subtract 20 from j 
RE:  
    mov eax, [jar] ; move the jar variable to the eax register to be pushed to the stack
    push  eax ; push jar for printf
    push message ; push formating for printf
    call printf   ; print the primary output "num: [jar]"
    pop eax ; clear the stack 
    pop eax ; clear the stack   
    mov eax, [incs]
    add [iar],eax
    cmp dword[iar],8 ; Compare iar to 8 to see if iar has been incremented 8 times   
    jl CMAIN ; if i != 8 jump to cmain
;pleaseKillMeNow:
   ; mov ah,0x4C  ;graceful exit
   ; int 0x21
```